# Invoking AWS CLI from Apex class

Tags: integration, interface

I need to invoke AWS Command Line Interface from a apex class. Can someone please help me in that?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not possible. A Salesforce org is very different from an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: You can invoke the AWS API directly though through HTTP callouts with Apex.

Comment: You cannot invoke any local CLI application from a browser-based app like Apex.  The security reasons are obvious.

Comment: As others mentioned - you definitely cannot invoke it directly, but you can leverage quite a rich ecosystem of AWS libraries. The correct way would be doing it via client-side JS utilising official SDK (https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-javascript/). Note that implementing this securely will require fairly serious IAM understanding. A bit lower hanging fruit would be using node.js wrapper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cli), potentially on something like Heroku and securely exposing your selected API calls using a shared secret and calling it from Apex.